# Why it's not possible to debug IscriptControl javascript code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, iscriptcontrol

I use visual studio 2008. When I set breakpoints on code they don't break. 
So only thing I can do is to debug "manually" using firefox with firebug.

Is there a way to debug with Visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just type `debugger;` into your javascript.

Comment: debugger; alert('aa'); this js code will be debugged when it hits the debugger.

Comment: worked, but why visual studio doesn't do it when i put break points?

Comment: because it is javascript :)basically you are attaching it to vs with that command.